# How to configure bat file in task scheduler with log file?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a python program `main.py` and it need to run on daily basis. It will print some information on CMD prompt, but I want those information in some text file.

I can configure this in bat file like below:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe  D:\main.py > D:\log\FileName_date.txt
```

The log file name should be `FileName_20150206.txt` for a run on the 06th feb 2015 and `FileName_20150207.txt` for a run on the 07th feb 2015.

Here the question is, how can I set or replace the date in the filename with a `YYMMDD` format, to configure the `.bat` file in task scheduler ?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer,

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%"
python D:\main.py > D:\log\FileName_%fullstamp%.txt
```

save this as a .bat file, and configure path of .bat file in scheduler.

Then you will get the log file in D:\log\FileName_2015-02-06.txt

Comment: If you use Python instead of cmd, getting the log name is simpler:  `import datetime;` `logname = r'D:\log\FileName_{:%Y-%m-%d}.txt'.format(datetime.date.today())`. Open the log file and pass it as `stdout` to `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: Yes, but that currently the program designed such a way that to print the log information in CMD. If the above case then I can modify the pgm to store the information in log file instead of cmd prompt.

Comment: I meant to run main.py using another Python script instead of a batch file, e.g. `logfile=open(logname, 'w');` `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, r'D:\main.py'], stdout=logfile).wait()`.

Comment: main.py is designed to print to its standard I/O file, `stdout`, which *may* be the console (I guess that's what you mean by CMD, but it has nothing to do with cmd.exe; the console window is conhost.exe). The batch script uses `>` to redirect stdout to the log file. That part is simpler than Python's `subprocess.Popen`, but getting the log file name is simpler in Python.

Comment: You could also just call Python to get the timestamp: `for /f %%a in ('python -c "import datetime;print(datetime.date.today())"') do set fullstamp=%%a`.